# Equivalent of "New directory" and "upload file" in Gitahead

Tags: gitlab, gitahead

In GitLab I use the two commands: "New directory" and "upload file" to add a file to my repository. How can I do this locally in Gitahead?

Answer (score 0):

Create new files and directories inside of your repository. When you open up GitAhead you will see them in the diff area with a question mark and check box next to their name. Click on the check box to stage them, then create a commit. Finally, click on push to upload your changes.

Comment: I am now able to create folders and new file. There is still the problem, that GitAhead does not recognize my changes. I found no other way than closing the project and reopen it again. Then the 'Stage all' button is present.